# MongoDB shuts down everyday - why and how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I have a ubuntu 16.04 server on OVH. I run mongod on it like this `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf &`

It gets down everyday and I am not able to find the reason.
I tried checking the logs but it's a huge file and I cannot find anything helpful.

Maybe you can help me with this?

Here is `mongo --version`

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Here are the server details

```
CPU
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz
Cores : 8
Cache : 8192KB

RAM
2x 8192MB

Disks
2 x 240 GB

Motherboard
P8B-M Series
```

And here is `mongod.conf`

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/mongodb_data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.17.0.10


#processManagement:

#security:
# authorization: enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

replication:
   replSetName: incredo


#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: With you having the log files and us having the skills to analyze them, I see a huge gap. There's simply not enough details for us to help you in any way.

Comment: @EsaJokinen maybe you tell me what I should search in the logs. I search and post the results here?

Comment: You can start by reading here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/ my best bet is to look for fatal and error messages but do read about the way mongo manages logs. If the log file is too big, rotate it and way for mongo to crash again.

Comment: How about the last log lines before your MongoDB server shuts down? If you are appending to logs, search for the lines before `initandlisten` (which should be logged when `mongod` starts). It would also be helpful to know some details about your environment: specific version of MongoDB server (x.y.z), total RAM, swap size, WiredTiger cache size (if not default), MongoDB data size, and host type (VM vs container vs bare metal). A common culprit for mysterious shutdowns on Linux is the [Out-of-Memory (OOM) killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/).

Comment: Thanks for adding some additional details. Were you able to find the log lines prior to shutdown? Try: `grep -B10 "\[initandlisten\] MongoDB starting" mongod.log` (should show 10 lines of context before the first startup message; you may need to increase that if the last message was a stack trace). The `mongod.conf` is helpful to confirm that there are no significant changes from the defaults and that this `mongod` is a member of a replica set. Are you seeing the same issues on other members of this replica set? What does your replica set config look like (# of members and roles)?

Comment: One notable missing server option is [`--fork`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-fork) on your `mongod` command-line (or the equivalent config option [`processManagement.fork`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#processManagement.fork) set to `true`). This is used to daemonize the `mongod` process to run in the background; otherwise it will terminate when your shell closes.

Comment: In a typical Linux install of MongoDB (particularly for production) you would normally use the service definition which takes care of the appropriate fork settings for a managed service (see: [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb)). Is there a reason you are running `mongod -f .. ` manually instead of using `service` ?

Comment: @Stennie I'll add the logs to the question, when I try `service mongod start` nothing happens.

Comment: @Stennie `--fork` may be what I am missing. The servers were setup by a devops guy and I don't know how he did it all and started mongo. After the initial crash I used the `mongod -f ..`

Comment: The command line should be `sudo service mongod start` (assuming you've stopped the `mongod` that you started manually). There should be no need to add `fork` if you use the default service definition. If the service doesn't start it will normally return an error. You could look in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` for more info. Another likely issue if you start `mongod` manually (as `root` or another user) is that you may now have inconsistent file permissions. Check the file perms via `ls -lat /home/mongodb_data`; all files should be owned by the same user & group (usually `mongodb:mongodb`).

Comment: @Stennie some of those are owned by root :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75250/discussion-between-hayk-safaryan-and-stennie).

Comment: @Stennie running mongod with fork seemed to fix the issue. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Besides I know there are some other things to be solved. You've been actually helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your backup script(s) are unreasonable and hog resources, causing the rest of the server's services to go down, every night while the backups run.